# How to add a row to data frame if there are different number of columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, insert

I have several dataframes with a single row per dataframe and I have an empty dataframe (*let's name it 'total'*). All dataframes have different count of columns, but some of them intersect. Total dataframe has all possible columns, so if I add any row from those dataframes it should match existed columns and fill values in accordance (*if a column doesn't exist in adding row it should be filled as 0*).

Example of dataframes with data:

```
A B C      B E      C E K J
1 2 5      4 2      3 2 5 7
```

Example of total dataframe:

```
A B C E K J
1 2 5 0 0 0
0 4 0 2 0 0
0 0 3 2 5 7
```

So, how to do that? I've tried various `bind`s and `insert`s but they don't work - in some cases added row changes total dataframe column amount, in some cases added row just duplicates previous row etc.

Comment: It would be better if you specify in which format you have this mini-dataframes (in a list maybe?).

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(.x, 0)))

#>   A B C E K J
#> 1 1 2 5 0 0 0
#> 2 0 4 0 2 0 0
#> 3 0 0 3 2 5 7
```

Comment: somehow replaces become `false` instead of 0

Comment: It is not `replace` but `replace_na`, @anatol. It works perfectly here.

Comment: I see, I didn't say 'I used replace'. I used your code absolutely as is

Comment: also, I'm getting an error `Can't combine '..1$A' <integer> and '..2$A' <list>`. does that mean my dataframes has different datatypes for same column?

Comment: Try this instead: `bind_rows(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x)))`.

Comment: You may have your `tidyverse` not updated, @anatol.

Comment: `ifelse` works fine

Comment: Great, @anatol!